# SqlDependency change work only for one change

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, service-broker, sqldependency

I'm working on project where I need to keep monitor on one of our database table, and for any new record insert I need to update the same on client.

For this, I'm using `SqlDependency` to subscribe the service broker. Also using SignalR to update the client side immediately.

My question is: my subscription is valid for only one change, once I get one update, don't know how, my subscription is removed automatically.

Here is the code which subscribe to the database for changes:

```
SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
SubScribeForAttendance();
SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
```

Subscription function:

```
public void SubScribeForAttendance()
{
    // We have selected the entire table as the command, so SQL Server executes this script and sees if there is a change in the result, raise the event
    string commandText = @"Select bnr,knrhex From dbo.TableName where bnr > SomeId";

    // Start the SQL Dependency
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            sqlDependency.OnChange += Dependency_OnBookingChange;

            // NOTE: You have to execute the command, or the notification will never fire.
            using (command.ExecuteReader())
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to re register sql dependency every time a notification is triggered, sql dependency only registers for one notification.

Call SubScribeForAttendance() at the last of Dependency_OnBookingChange to re register sql dependency

I found this solution from this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/883702/Real-Time-Notifications-using-SignalR-and-SQL-Depe)

Comment: So Re subscribe is the only option ? Can't we do register for multiple changes ?

Comment: No, sql server only registers for one change, once triggered it releases the  hook.